# pramid.security.remember secure?

Tags: python, security, authentication, cookies, pyramid

I wondered if this is secure, and I don't know how remeber is working. If I log off via forget, I can still view the auth_tkt cookie in my browser, so I thought that it couldn't be as simple as encrypting the user_id and store them in a cookie, is it?

EDIT:
My login code:

```
headers = remember(request,user.userId)
return HTTPFound(location="/",headers=headers)
```

Logoff code:

```
headers = forget(request)
return HTTPFound(location="/login",headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

pyramid.security.remember uses HMAC to sign cookies which makes it close to tamper-proof.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac

Regarding your question about forget, are you passing the new request without the cookie to the headers?

```
headers = forget(request)
return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('home'),
                 headers = headers)
```

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html#adding-login-and-logout-views

Also it helps if you show us what you have tried, maybe including your logout view code

Comment: Thank you! I can't actually use the app if I logged off, maybe Chrome caches the "View cookies" page somehow.

Comment: @FelixScheinost if im not mistaken chrome renders all their settings pages with html like a webpage would do, so a refresh would be needed to see if cookies changed :)

Comment: Oh, I forget. I'm surprised that Chrome wouldn't use something nice like background refreshing. I also tested it another way, logging in in two different browsers the same time also produces different auth_tkt's

Comment: @FelixScheinost thats because the HMAC takes the time the cookie was modified into its calculation making it harder to tamper with. You can also set it to remember IP so it invalidates if IP changes. `authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('mysecret', include_ip=True)` http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/authentication.html#module-pyramid.authentication

Comment: the AuthTkt policy does **not** actually use HMAC. It uses `md5(md5(timestamp+secret+userid+'\0'+tokens+'\0'+userdata) + secret)`. Regardless, the rest of this is true. It's tamper-proof but not encrypted, meaning the data is visible to the user.